# Django block user login from incognito browser window if user is already logged in from regular browser window

Tags: python, django

Let's say, I have a user who has logged in using Chrome browser normal window(not incognito), now he opens an incognito window tries to login using same credentials, I want to detect that the particular user is logged in already and disallow a second login.

I have seen few questions like this, where solution is to clear up all older sessions. But, is it the only solution? Can't I have all those sessions untouched and still guarantee that there be only one active session.

Comment: How do you determine an "active session"?

Comment: I understand 'active session' is not a perfect term, but to explain it I would say if a user logs in successfully from lets say Chrome browser, its one active session for that particular user. I don't want to allow that user to login from any other browser there after. I would rather show user a message saying he/she has to log out from anyother browser in that case to login.

Comment: But "not logging out" doesn't determine an active session. Most users never log out. But what if they close their browser, or shut down the computer, or just leave the tab open for months behind 100 other ones?

Comment: Agree with what you are saying, l do have setup browser length cookies by using SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE variable and a timeout of 30 mins. So in those cases, logging out and session cleaning up happens smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the ip address of the user in real time and check if there is some active session related to that ip address.

If it is there, it will block the user from using it in incognito or any other browser.

And active session means open session here

Comment: As Daniel Roseman said, what if the user closes the browser and opens a new browser window and tries to login again? Won't he be blocked?

Comment: No, because until he specifically logs out, that session would be open. and until he is using the same browser, closing the window, or the tab won't matter. For this, donot give them the option to logout as quora does. Also set the cookie expiration time very high.

Comment: Otherwise just check whether cookies are enabled in browser or not. If not, do not allow them. make a decorator for that